# Does libre office writer encrypt temp files when .odt file is encrypted?

Tags: encryption, libreoffice, openoffice, odt

I used Libre Office Writer to create an encrypted .odt file. LibreOffice uses temp files by default.

Are the temp files encrypted while working with the file if the file has been encrypted in the first place?

Is the content of the file encrypted throughout without any way of extracting the content in cases such as the Writer crashing while editing the file leaving behind some unencrypted temp files?

I'm curious about the behavior on Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: Why not test it yourself? You have Libre Office Writer installed right?